# Finding solution for a differential equation in the form $\frac{dC}{dt}=k_2B$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have these three differential equations.

a) Find the solution for $$\displaystyle\frac{dA}{dt}=-k_1A \ , \ \ A(0)=N$$

Okay we have $\displaystyle\frac{dA}{dt}+k_1A=0$ so it is homogeneous and the solution is given by $A(t)=ce^{-k_1t}$. Then we have $A(0)=c=N$. We are ending up with $$A(t)=Ne^{-k_1t}$$

b) Now use $A(t)$ to find the solution for $$\displaystyle\frac{dB}{dt}=k_1A-k_2B \ , \ \ B(0)=0$$

Here we have $\displaystyle\frac{dB}{dt}+k_2B=k_1A$, and I put in my A, $\displaystyle\frac{dB}{dt}+k_2B=k_1Ne^{-k_1t}$  so it is nonhomogeneous and the solution is given by $$B(t)=B_h(t)+B_p(t)$$

First I will find $B_h(t)$, which means $\displaystyle\frac{dB}{dt}+k_2B=0$. Like in the previous we have $B_h(t)=ce^{-k_2t}$.

Now I will find $B_p(t)$, and I my guess is $B_p(t)=Ae^{-k_1t}$. I differentiate it, $B_p'(t)=-Ak_1e^{-k_1t}$.

Then I will put that into the equatin:
$-Ak_1e^{-k_1t}+k_2Ae^{-k_1t}=k_1Ne^{-k_1t}$. Now isolate $A$:

$$A(-k_1e^{-k_1t}+k_2e^{-k_1t})=k_1Ne^{-k_1t}$$
$$A=\frac{k_1Ne^{-k_1t}}{-k_1e^{-k_1t}+k_2e^{-k_1t}}$$
$$A=\frac{k_1Ne^{-k_1t}}{e^{-k_1t}(-k_1+k_2)}$$
$$A=\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2}$$

Put this into my guess: $B_p(t)=\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t}$

Then $B(t)=ce^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t}$, and $B(0)=c+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2}=0$. We see that $c=-\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2}$ So the solution is
$$B(t)=-\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t}$$

c) Now use $B(t)$ to find the solution for $$\displaystyle\frac{dC}{dt}=k_2B \ , \ \ C(0)=0$$

I put in $B(t)$.

$$\frac{dC}{dt}=k_2 \left(-\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t} \right)$$

$$dC=k_2 \left(-\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t} \right)dt$$

$$C=\int k_2 \left(-\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t} \right)dt$$

$$C=\int -\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_2t}+\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} \cdot e^{-k_1t} dt$$

$$C=-\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} \int e^{-k_2t} dt +\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} \int e^{-k_1t} dt$$

$$C=-\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} -\frac{e^{-k_2t}}{k_2} +\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2N}{-k_1+k_2} -\frac{e^{-k_1t}}{k_1}$$

$$C=\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2Ne^{-k_2t}}{(-k_1+k_2)k_2} -\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2Ne^{-k_1t}}{(-k_1+k_2)k_1}$$
Am I correct with c)?

Comment: Just integrate both sides of the last one with respect to $t$ and you are done.

Comment: But am I good so far?

Comment: I edited c) can you take a look at it?